# How to show canvas objects in latest version of chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, canvas, pdf.js

I am using pdfjs in asp.net for showing pdf in chrome. Output is shown as canvas objects with multiple divs in it and output is shown correctly in chrome Version 42.0.2311.152 dev-m. But when chrome is updated to its latest version pdfjs output is not shown.

In firefox there is no such issue but our requirement are to use chrome.

Through inspect element following is rendered in pdf display of chrome older version (42.0.2311.152 dev-m). In latest version of chrome no such divs are rendered.

```
<div class="textLayer">    
    <div data-canvas-width="77.60424613952638" data-font-name="Helvetica" style="font-size: 41.0604px; left: 375.977px; top: 276.366px; transform: scale(1.00785, 1); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;" dir="ltr" data-text-length="4"></div>
    <div data-canvas-width="132.65090882778168" data-font-name="Helvetica" style="font-size: 12.8314px; left: 162.935px; top: 348.975px; transform: scale(0.997375, 1); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;" dir="ltr" data-text-length="24"></div>
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
</div>
```

Link for pdfjs https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Comment: i have installed chrome Version 45.0.2415.0 canary (64-bit) but still no display

Comment: Could you add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: the problem is solved when i used latest pdfjs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved when i used latest pdfjs file.